# Error getting new calendar for new reminders

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, reminders

I'm trying to add a feature in my application so the user can get a list of reminders using the following method.

The following method is the main method I'm using for retrieving the reminders:

```
func getReminders(){

    var eventStore : EKEventStore = EKEventStore()    
    // This lists every reminder
    var calender = getCalender(eventStore)
    let calendars = eventStore.calendarsForEntityType(EKEntityTypeReminder)
        as! [EKCalendar]

    //cals.append(calender)
    var predicate = eventStore.predicateForRemindersInCalendars([calender])
    eventStore.fetchRemindersMatchingPredicate(predicate) { reminders in
        for reminder in reminders {
            println(reminder.title)

            self.remindersTitles.append(reminder.title!!)
        }}
    var startDate=NSDate().dateByAddingTimeInterval(-60*60*24)
    var endDate=NSDate().dateByAddingTimeInterval(60*60*24*3)
    var predicate2 = eventStore.predicateForEventsWithStartDate(startDate, endDate: endDate, calendars: nil)

    println("startDate:\(startDate) endDate:\(endDate)")
    var eV = eventStore.eventsMatchingPredicate(predicate2) as! [EKEvent]!

    if eV != nil {
        for i in eV {
            println("Title  \(i.title!)" )
            println("stareDate: \(i.startDate)" )
            println("endDate: \(i.endDate)" )
        }
    }
}
```

As you notice I'm creating a calendar and assign it the return value of a method called 'getCalender':

```
func getCalender(store: EKEventStore) -> EKCalendar {
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    if let id = defaults.stringForKey("GSCalender") {
        return store.calendarWithIdentifier(id)
    } else {
        var calender = EKCalendar(forEntityType: EKEntityTypeReminder, eventStore: store)
        calender.title = "Genie Sugar Calender!"
        calender.CGColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
        calender.source = store.defaultCalendarForNewReminders().source!
        var error: NSError?

        store.saveCalendar(calender, commit: true, error: &error)

        if error == nil {
            defaults.setObject(calender.calendarIdentifier, forKey: "GSCalender")
        }

        if calender == nil {
            println("nothing here")
        }
        return calender
    }
}
```

But the issue is that the application is stuck at this line of the second method:

```
calender.source = store.defaultCalendarForNewReminders().source!
```

And returns me this error:

> Error getting default calendar for new reminders: Error Domain=EKCADErrorDomain Code=1013 "The operation couldn’t be completed.

Any ideas please to overcome this problem? with my advanced thanks

Comment: I have the same issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating an EKCalendar in EKEventStore - Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29286359/creating-an-ekcalendar-in-ekeventstore-swift)

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the iPhone simulator, after it being reset - returns nil for store.defaultCalendarForNewReminders(). I believe it is a simulator bug.

Answer (score 0):

By doing lots of tests, I came up with an observation that the simulators can fetch **defaultCalendarForNewReminders()** smoothly (*with calendar usage permission*)....but with the testing on a real device with iOS 14.6 it is returning nil, even an iPhone has the default calendar for events already!

I had also tried with **EKCalendarChooser** in order to select other calendars, but still it not worked!
So I think it is an iOS bug.